# Removing unwanted keys from my array of objects

Tags: javascript

My Object

How to remove keys like UserID, UserName from it... i mean selected keys... delete operator is not working in my case.

```
for (i=0 i <obj.length; i ++) {
    delete obj[i]['keyName']; 
}
```

The above does not work, neither throws an error. Any other way...

Comment: `delete` should work. Show the full code

Comment: You're probably using `for` loop the wrong way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this solution....

```
Array.prototype.containsValue = function (value) {
        for (var k in this) {
            if (!this.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
                continue;
            } //skip inherited properties
            if (this[k] == value) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    };

for (var key in Object) {
    var unwantedKeys = ['UserName', 'UserID'];
    if (unwantedKeys.containsValue(key)) continue;
    // Play with your Object it won't contain these unwanted keys.
}
```

Delete should work, i am not sure about the mistake you are doing..

http://jsfiddle.net/spechackers/43hTD/

Comment: @John: as a reminder, it's generally bad practice to use a `for...in` loop on arrays.  Order of iteration is not guaranteed and any non-index enumerable properties will also be iterated over.  Just something to think about if you're implementing this solution.

Comment: @Andy E: Are you talking about the fiddle or my other response... i was just showing the OP that delete works...

Comment: @Vinothbabu: I'm talking about the `Array.prototype.containsValue` function here, which uses a `for...in` loop to iterate over `this`.  `this` would be an array, so `for...in` isn't really appropriate to use.

Answer (score 6):

You missed the `;` after `i=0`.

Additionally, `obj` needs to be `MyObject.PatientVitalsGetResult.Vitals`

Comment: `MyObject.PatientVitalsGetResult.Vitals` actualy

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `delete`; it will set the element to undefined instead of removing it. Instead, use `splice`.

```
var i;
for(i = 0; i < obj.length; i++){
    obj[i].splice('keyName',1);
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the goal is to remove a named key from each object in an array, not individual array elements.

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard way for this, afaik. You will need to perform a conditional copy of the  old `Object` filtering the unwanted properties:

```
var oldObject = { /* your object */ } ;
var newObject = { } ;

var filter = { "UserID": true , "UserName": true } ;

for(var key in oldObject) 
    if( !(key in filter) ) newObject[key] = oldObject[key] ;
```

Then use the acquired `newObject` in the following code.

Comment: I don't understand your criticism. How is this approach "costly"? How is it "not needed" (especially if there is no other way to remove entries from an `Object`).

Answer (score 1):

```
var vitals = obj["PatientVitalsGetResult"]["Vitals"];


for (i=0; i < vitals.length; i++) {
    delete(vitals[i]["UserID"])
};
```